# Why is my sudo process freezing?

Tags: sudo, networkmanager, window-manager, freeze

When my laptop is at work (running OpenSUSE Tumbleweed), and when the network cable -> USB adapter is plugged in, eventually in a day the computer sort-of-freezes. I can still operate everything normally, but as soon as I attempt any sudo command, the process attempting it freezes; this includes sudo reboot. On the other hand, doing an su -s still seems to work. It's purely the sudo that is frozen, and it seems to be related to being plugged in to the network via the USB adapter.

As a side note, this does NOT happen when I use KDE as my window manager; however, I usually use exwm (emacs). I can't even think of a possible explanation. Any ideas?

Comment: What the brand and model of your notebook? does it have an ethernet  port?

Comment: Access to `/etc/sudo.conf` sounds like one of the suspects.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No ethernet port; it's a Dell XPS 13

Comment: defining your hostname in /etc/hosts is it possible, and does it solve the problem?

Comment: In this case, I would be more inclined that you could be using a dodgy ethernet adapter. Please details the brand and/or the output of `lsbusb` command in the question. However, the XPS 13 has known wifi problems due to bad design of the board.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro lsbusb is not a command my system has, or one that cnf can locate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;**

In my case I fixed adding `Defaults  !fqdn` to the `/etc/sudoers` file

**Details:**

Maybe is freezing due to a network problem. Fix the network, then sudo will work again, I hope.

I was with similar problem (on Ubuntu Mate) and seems that we have kind of a cyclical dependency:

- By some reason sudo needs network (to validate a hostname based configuration, probably)
- The network is not working
- To fix the network I need to run $ sudo killall NetWorkManager; sudo NetWorkManager
- But any command that I run with sudo freezes the terminal

So, to summarize:

- To fix network I need sudo
- To run sudo I need network

For me, the initial workaround was define a password for root, then I can login and restart the NetworkManager. Then I realized that I can add "Defaults  !fqdn" to sudoers file and fixed the problem.

Comment: can't edit sudoers without sudo tho...